# Making a link the full size of the block

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm adapting a portfolio code that was kindly posted by James here: http://codepen.io/SeamlessThemes/pen/LiBdo

I've managed to change most things that I need, but I can't for the life of me get the href to cover the responsive block. At the moment only the "View" link and padding are active.

I'll reproduce the code here so that you don't need to visit codepen if you'd rather not

```css
* {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
}

.view {
    width: 32.33%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #079;
}
.view:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
.view .mask, .view .content {
    width: 32.33%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
.view img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.view h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #222;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.view p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center
}
.view a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.view a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}



.view-portfolio img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-portfolio .mask {
   background-color: #222;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-300px);
   transform: translateX(-300px);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.view-portfolio h2 {
   background: #222;
   color: #FFF;
}
.view-portfolio p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   color: #FFF;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-portfolio:hover .mask {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
   -o-transform: translateX(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
   transform: translateX(0px);
}
.view-portfolio:hover img {
   -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
   -o-transform: translateX(300px);
   -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
   transform: translateX(300px);
}
.view-portfolio:hover p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="view view-portfolio">
                    <img src="http://locallylost.com/chun/files/2013/01/manhattansummer.jpg">
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Portfolio Item 1</h2>
                        <p>This is an example portfolio item exceprt.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-portfolio">
                    <img src="http://locallylost.com/chun/files/2013/01/manhattansummer.jpg">
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Portfolio Item 2</h2>
                        <p>This is another example portfolio item exceprt.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="view view-portfolio">
                    <img src="http://locallylost.com/chun/files/2013/01/manhattansummer.jpg">
                    <div class="mask">
                        <h2>Portfolio Item 3</h2>
                        <p>This is yet another example portfolio item exceprt.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="info">View</>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. 
You want to on hover be able to press anywhere the image?

Comment: You want .view a.info to cover the parent div.view? of course with display:inline-block you're not achieving it

Comment: just put an <a> tag around your <div class="view view-portfolio">

Comment: I'd like people to be able to click on the whole of the portfolio element, not just the word "View" and it's padded background. Removing the "display:inline-block" didn't change anything, and I'm afraid the wrapped link didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
.view a.info {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
```

}

You can adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question but if you want a link on the image...

```
<div class="view view-portfolio">
      <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">
           <img src="http://locallylost.com/chun/files/2013/01/manhattansummer.jpg">
      </a>
      <div class="mask">
           <h2>Portfolio Item 1</h2>
           <p>This is an example portfolio item exceprt.</p>
           <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This just makes the clickable area 100% width, but not height. The image is covered with the mask. This doesn't improve even when the a tags wrap around the mask div.